# Reach Java Servlet from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

How can reach a JavaServlet from JavaScript?

My html-File in the path `P08_BillBoard/web/billboard.html` . Addtionally, the `billboard.js` is in the same directory.
The servlet-File is in  `P08_BillBoard/src/java/de/vs/Billboard.java` .

Now, if I try to run the application, I get the following error from the browser:

> POSThttp://localhost:63342/P08_BillBoard/web/BillBoardServer

> 404 Not Found

The code of the POST-Request in the billboard.js is:

```
function postHttpRequest(url) {
    var xmlhttp = getXMLHttpRequest(); 
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            getHttpRequest(url);
            document.getElementById("something").value = "";
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send("value="+document.getElementById("something").value);
}
```

I guess the problem is the path, but how looks the modification of the code?

Comment: `The servlet-File is in P08_BillBoard/src/java/de/vs/Billboard.java` but your 404 is pointing to something quite different. ........ The relative of your 404 is `P08_BillBoard/web/BillBoardServer`, meanwhile your question simply doesn't include this code for some reason.

Comment: How can I include the code?

Comment: Should be an option to "edit" your question?

Comment: Yes, that's possible